# tmux status bar messages last only about a second: can I extend this?

Tags: tmux

I've searched through the man pages several times for a way to set the length of time that status bar messages (what you see if you enter `display-message "hello world"` at a tmux command prompt) are visible, but there seems to be nothing.   Does anyone know a way I can make them stay long enough to be read.  Particularly annoying are error messages I get after entering a command with some syntax error.  I have to repeat the command 3 or more times just to be able to get some idea what it says.

Does anyone know how to fix this?  (Preferably without changing the source code and recompiling ;)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

It sounds like you want to change the `display-time` session option. The initial default value is 750 milliseconds.

If you want to set a new, default value, then change the “global” value (e.g. in your `.tmux.conf`):

```
set-option -g display-time 4000
```

The global value will be effective for any sessions that have not established their own value (see below).

If you just want to change a single session (e.g. change only the current session, via a Prefix-`:` command line):

```
set-option display-time 4000
```

---

Of course (like any other *tmux* command), you can also make the changes from a shell command line:

```
tmux set-option -g display-time 4000
tmux set-option -t 4 display-time 10000  # set a value just for session "4"
```

Comment: Thanks!  display-time wasn't in the PDF of the man pages I was using (on account of man pages not getting installed locally on my machine for some reason).

Answer (score 37):

There is also the `show-messages` command bound to `~` by default.

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to use `display-message -p`. The behavior of `-p` is tmux temporarily opens an empty, dedicated window, to display the message. What's nice is that window is automatically in tmux's copy mode. The message (and the window) only dismisses when you press a key.

This is more intrusive then the regular `display-message`, but definitely catches user attention. More like a modal dialog in the GUI's term.

```
     display-message [-aIpv] [-c target-client] [-t target-pane] [message]
                   (alias: display)
             Display a message.  If -p is given, the output is printed to stdout, otherwise it is displayed in the target-client status line.  The format of message is described in the FORMATS section; information is taken from target-pane if -t is given, otherwise the
             active pane.

             -v prints verbose logging as the format is parsed and -a lists the format variables and their values.

             -I forwards any input read from stdin to the empty pane given by target-pane.
```

Comment: I cannot see a relation to OP's question. This is more like `echo <whatever>` but does not display the latest tmux client message. `show-messages` does the job in a "modal" dialog.